# How to split a text by words instead of .?! marks using Regex Split?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to split a text by different words and not by periods. Here is a code I tried:

```
string StringFromTheInput = TextBox1.Text;
string[] splichar1 = Regex.Split(StringFromTheInput, @"(?<=[\because\and\now\this is])");
```

I want to use these words or phrases as delimiter in text instead of period mark, this is an example what output I need:

```
 Text: Sentence blah blah blahh because bblahhh balh and blahhh
 Output: because bblahhh balh and blahhh

 another example-
```

Text:  bla now blahhh

Output: now blahhh

Comment: I want to split a text into sentences but instead of period mark [.]  I want text parts to be seperated by some words, a normal text split would be this: Regex.Split(StringFromTheInput, @"(?<=[\.!?])");  but I want this Regex.Split(StringFromTheInput, @"(?<=[\because\and\now\this is])");

Comment: Now I got this error: parsing "(?<=(if|and|but|so|when)" - Not enough )'s.

Comment: I think the answer of @ZakariaNajim helps you.

Comment: Hi,is my answer helpful?

Comment: Yiyi You - partialy I applied only regular expresssions from your code cause I still need to use Regex.Split: heres is the code I used: string[] splichar1 = Regex.Split(StringFromTheInput, @"s\(because|and|now|this is)\s"); this code whenever finds a word of these "because" "and" etc splits the part of a text but I want to split the text so that the splitted text involves the keywords "because" "and"' in the beginning of the splitted text -> for example because + splitted text; and + splitted text; I hope I could explain some...

Answer (score 2):

- You can do it with `String.Contains Method` and `String.Substring Method`.

*Code:*

```
string stringfromtheinput = "Sentence blah blah blahh because bblahhh balh and blahhh";
String[] spearator = {
  "because",
  "and",
  "now",
  "this is"
};

foreach(string x in spearator) {
  if (stringfromtheinput.Contains(x)) {
    Console.WriteLine(stringfromtheinput.Substring(stringfromtheinput.LastIndexOf(x)));
  }
}
```

*Output:*

```
because bblahhh balh and blahhh
and blahhh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find the position of `\because\and\now\this is`,and then use `substring`.

```
string StringFromTheInput = TextBox1.Text;
 string str="";
            var match = Regex.Match(s, @"\b(because|and|now|this is)\b");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var index=match.Index; // 25
                str = s.Substring(index);//str is what you want
            }
```

Output:

```
because bblahhh balh and blahhh
```

Comment: Yiyi You - partialy I applied only regular expresssions from your code cause I still need to use Regex.Split: heres is the code I used: string[] splichar1 = Regex.Split(StringFromTheInput, @"\s(because|and|now|this is)\s"); this code whenever finds a word of these "because" "and" etc splits the part of a text but I want to split the text so that the splitted text involves the keywords "because" "and"' in the beginning of the splitted text -> for example because + splitted text; and + splitted text; I hope I could explain some..